# Bullets don't move forward, but stay stuck in the gun's location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, game-development

When the game starts on the client [localserver], the bullets don't move forward in space. They just stay fixed in the gun's location. See the image below for an illustration of the issue:

[image]

```
 Network Manegar: https://imgur.com/mfcBo61
Player: https://imgur.com/DuOIy67
Bullet: https://imgur.com/cVq5HFU
```

and this my script

```
    void Update()
   {
      if (!isLocalPlayer)
      {
         return;
      }
      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
      {
         CmdBulletFire();
      }
   }
  [Command]
  void CmdBulletFire()
  {
    // create the bullet prefab
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);

    //add velocity to bullet
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * 50000f));
    //Spawn the bullet
    NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);
    //Destroy the bullet
    Destroy(bullet, 5f);
  }
```

What could the issue be, and how do I resolve it?

Still the Problem :(

Comment: This should probably be moved to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ - we don't see a lot of non-web based questions here

Comment: @KaiQing Unity3D questions, when programming related, are perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: @Bart - Looks like we'll see by whether or not OJ's solution works. Otherwise I got a suspicion this will grow cobwebs.

Comment: @KaiQing If it grows cobwebs here, it'll get them on Game Dev too.

Answer (score 4):

In your update function, you have to make sure that this is the `isLocalPlayer` before calling `CmdBulletFire()`.

Your new Update function:

```
void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        CmdBulletFire();
    }
}
```

Finally, make sure you do the following:

1.Attach `NetworkTransform` and `NetworkIdentity` components to the prefab.

2.Register the prefab to the NetworkManager:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njLZD.png)

Comment: I do that , but the problem is still :(

Comment: I don't know how to help you more. Can you edit your answer and add your new code. Also show proof that you have done what I said in #1 and #2. You can do those two with a screenshot of the Inspector tab

Comment: Oh well it seems ok to me. I would have preferred if you added new code in your edit instead of removing the old one in your question. Can you even check that this works in non network code? Also, what happens when you add force with velocity instead of AddForce? `bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity * bullet.transform.forward * 100f`; ?

Comment: in non network I don't have any problem , but with network here the problem, when set velocity the bullet Scattered

Comment: Did you try the `bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity * bullet.transform.forward * 100f;` I talked about instead of `bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * 50000f));`? If this doesn't work then I don't know what your current issue is

Comment: I'm rooting for you, but I genuinely believe you'll get better attention from the game dev stack exchange site linked in my comment above. I'm a web programmer / game dev so I know where you'll get a right proper response whether or not this is considered on topic here. I use stack overflow to answer web issues. I use gamedev to answer game dev questions... just sayin. Good luck and yay unity. My favorite game is a unity game and I want it to thrive. Rooting for you.

Comment: @kai Qing , thank u , https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/158411/what-issue-in-the-shot-in-unity-3d , I hope found the answer .